# Cleanup Document in Eclipse not working in specific case

Tags: eclipse, xslt

I have a problem using Eclipse Cleanup Document option in case my XML looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<div>

    <span style='color:#0000C8'>&gt;
</span>

<h3 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><a name="_Toc419970681">2.7.2<span
style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>Helpers</a></h3>

</div>
```

Clean document works only if I remove `<div>` tags or if I move `</span>` after `&gt;`

After successful [Source - Cleanup Document] XML should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<div>

  <span style='color:#0000C8'>&gt;</span>

  <h3 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'>
    <a name="_Toc419970681">
      2.7.2
      <span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </span>
      Helpers
    </a>
  </h3>

</div>
```

Comment: You can put  &gt; followed by </span> tag.

Answer (score 0):

May be due to > (>) eclipse consider it as closing tag of span. Hence it can not validate other content after > as this is not proper closing tag of span/div. If you remove DIV tag then it will not find any open tag except span to treats as > however it did not removes you  tag at the end.